# yo gulp-webapp + BrowserSync

Tags: yeoman, gulp

I want to use gulp-webapp with php server (not the default built in one).

my gulp file [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/TheSpiritMolecule/637b8d765cc11163915e), but here is the extracted part:

```
    gulp.task('serve', ['styles'], function () {
    browserSync.init("*", {
        debugInfo: true,
        open: true,
        proxy: "localhost/nl_mobile/app"
    })
});


gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function () {

    // watch for changes
    gulp.watch(['app/*.html'], reload);

    gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['images']);
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);

    gulp.watch('app/bower_components/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/bower_components/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

The problem is, the changed content inject to the browser but it does not refresh itself, i have to refresh it manually.

I also changed this line:

```
// .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'))
```

because, i cannon't specify

```
server: {
    baseDir: ['app', '.tmp'],
    directory: true
},
```

because it will fire up some kind of http based server which doesn't understand php :(

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't run across the answer already, Browser Sync supports a `proxy` config option that can be used to reverse proxy another web server, e.g. Apache, `php -S`. You'll also need to watch the PHP files in your project for updates to trigger the reload in the attached browsers. Happy to expound with examples as needed.